# Alternatives to Curl in CentOS

Tags: curl, client, webserver, put

is there any other efficient alternative clients to CURL in Centos by which I can send a PUT request to Upload a file to the webserver that is installed in the host?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Curl is the de-facto command line tool for that sort of malarkey over http

to transfer files you can also use:

ftp
sftp
scp
smbclient

I could go on, you will need to be more specific

Comment: Actually I'm sending a PUT request using http 1.1 by CURL to lighttpd webserver in order to do some experiments. But CURL doesn't seem to send the request in a proper manner. So, I'm looking for a better alternative to CURL.

Comment: do you have any logs from you lighttpd server that show how it interprets the curl PUT?